# How to use === with condition?

Tags: syntax, expression-manipulation, conditional, expression-test, testing-and-verification

I have two expressions, and they are same when `k` is positive and `x` is non-zero real number. Below code gives me `False` as output. How can I get `True` as output when I apply the condition?

```
Min[k, Max[-k, x]]/x === Min[1, k/Abs[x]]
```

Many thanks!

Comment: `===` is for structural equality, `==` is for mathematical equality. I believe you intend to check for the latter.

Comment: Amplifying on @Szabolcs comment, evaluate `Assuming[{k > 0, Element[x, Reals], x != 0}, 
 Min[k, Max[-k, x]]/x == Min[1, k/Abs[x]] // Simplify]`